# How to create a dynamic SectionList?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to build a section list where the list header is the name of a class (like a school class) and the section list is the assignments that are assigned to that class.

This is my section list component:

```
<SectionList
          sections={classData}
          keyExtractor={item => item.class.id}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section: classProps }) => {
            return (
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{classProps.name}</Text>
            );
          }}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <HomeworkItem
                homeworkItem={item}
                deleteHomework={() => this.props.removeHomework(item)}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
```

This is the code to get `classData`:

```
    const classData = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < this.props.classes.length; x++) {
      classData.push({
        classProps: this.props.classes[x],
        assignments: this.filterAssignments(this.props.classes[x], this.props.homework)
      });
    }
```

And the filter assignments function is this:

```
filterAssignments(c, hw) {
    return hw.filter(item => item.className === c.name);
  }
```

I am receiving an error that `items.length` is undefined at the beginning of the list. The data appears to be working. If anyone knows how I can do this correctly your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the `.bind(this)` isn't needed for a function that doesn't use `this`

Comment: Ok, now it is saying 'items.length' is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a variable called `items`? On which line does it occur?

Comment: Occurs on line 31 which is ```<SectionList```

Comment: The `classData` does not seem to conform to the specified format, check the added answer

Comment: Could you please show the complete code for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) state the following format:

```js
const DATA = [
  {
    title: 'Main dishes',
    data: ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Risotto'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Sides',
    data: ['French Fries', 'Onion Rings', 'Fried Shrimps'],
  }
];
```

this format can be achieved with the following loop:

```
const classData = this.props.classes.map(item => ({
  title: item.name
  data: this.filterAssignments(item, this.props.homework)
}));
```

the `classData` can now be passed to `<SectionList` as such:

```
<SectionList
          sections={classData}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the filterAssignments function ? What if my data is a list of expenses as described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525341/how-to-filter-from-two-different-arrays-in-react-native where I want to display the expenses as list grouped using month?